# How can I display different versions of my website to the visitors randomly with the same probability?

Tags: javascript, web

I have three different versions of my website which I would like to show them to my visitors randomly. For example when the first user visited my webpage I would like to show version-1 of my website, when the second user visited my webpage, I would like to show version-2, for the third user displays version-3 and for the next user version-1 again and so on…

Could anyone tell me please what would be the right approach to this problem, would be any JavaScript code that I could put in my main webpage to take control of this action?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is for people looking for answers to problems they've attempted to solve but cannot find a solution. It is not for suggesting approaches to a script. Try to look up tutorials about how this works, there are bound to be some good ones online.

Comment: Do you want it to be random or in a sequential repeating order? Please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: What are "versions"? You mean templates? Or only an image in the header?

Comment: Can you use PHP? It would be easy to store the visited pages in a .txt file and pick a random number out of those not already chose.

Comment: Only three different websites (main.html) i.e.
www.example1.com
www.example2.com
www.example3.com
Which I am going to integrate and display these three within my main website website.
For example when people go the main website: www.general-web.com, they will see those three website randomly. Hope this make it clear ;)

Comment: My main website actually does not support PHP, it only support JavaScript. However I would appreciate if you can give me PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP and a JSON file:

```
<?php
  $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.json'), true);
  if(count($arr) >= 3) $arr = array();
  $searching = true;
  while($searching){
    $page = rand(0,3);
    if(!array_search($page,$arr)){
      $searching = false;
      array_push($arr,$page);
    }
  }
  file_put_contents("array.json",json_encode($arr));
  // the page number is $page
?>
```

Comment: @user5160805 rename your html file to _file.php_ then add this code at the top of it. At the part of your code where you must know the page, add `<?php echo $page ?>`, it will add the page number to your html/js code. Sorry for the delay.